# How to find the min and max frequency interval in CoreMotion framework

Tags: ios, sensors, core-motion

In iOS CoreMotion Framework, I can set the frequency interval for accelerometer, magnetometer, etc. and capture the data at a specified interval. But it's mentioned in the documentation that, the min and max frequency is dependant on the hardware of the device. How can I know the min and max intervals that I can provide? What happens if I provide the interval value less and min interval of the hardware?

Similarly, how can I find the min and max values (full scale range) of the sensors information being provided by CoreMotion Framework?

Answer (score 3):

Apple docs:

> **Choosing a Motion Event Update Interval**
>
> When you request motion data with Core Motion, you specify an update interval. You should choose the largest interval that meets your app’s needs. The larger the interval, the fewer events are delivered to your app, which improves battery life.
>
> Table 4-1 lists some common update frequencies and explains what you can do with data generated at that frequency. Few apps need acceleration events delivered 100 times a second.
>
> Event frequency (Hz) Usage
>
> 10–20 Suitable for determining a device’s current orientation vector.
>
> 30–60 Suitable for games and other apps that use the accelerometer for real-time user input.
>
> 70–100 Suitable for apps that need to detect high-frequency motion. For example, you might use this interval to detect the user hitting the device or shaking it very quickly.
>
> You can set the reporting interval to be as small as 10 milliseconds (ms), which corresponds to a 100 Hz update rate, but most app operate sufficiently with a larger interval.

In a nutshell: 10Hz-100Hz

Source: [Choosing a Motion Event Update Interval](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW15)

Comment: N.B: I was able to use 100Hz. However, I would get timestamps in the wrong order. I ignore whether this is a bug or not, but the highest frequency I was able to use without any issue (that I know of) was 89Hz.

Comment: anyone know what the default is?

Answer (score 1):

Please look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html 
Pay attention on:When you request motion data with Core Motion, you specify an update interval. You should choose the largest interval that meets your app’s needs. The larger the interval, the fewer events are delivered to your app, which improves battery life. Table 4-1 lists some common update frequencies and explains what you can do with data generated at that frequency. Few apps need acceleration events delivered 100 times a second